# Code highlighting broken?

Tags: bug, code-formatting

On Windows 10 with Firefox 93.0 I get this interesting to read code:

[image: Code broken]

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36615330/995926)

Comment: No repro, FF94b on Win10

Comment: No repro: FF93.0/Win 10. I tried light mode and light high contrast mode, just in case but still nothing.

Comment: No repro on Win 10 Chrome 94.0.4606.81 either. Maybe try clearing cache? The highlighter only changes CSS classes on code blocks, and shouldn't really be changing the content of them or the characters used within them.

Comment: If anything it doesn't look like code highlighting is broken, but instead you look like you're missing a font.

Comment: ^^^^ Especially since the inline code in the paragraphs above the block isn't rendering either.

Comment: Not sure to be honest I cleared the cache already

Comment: Any extensions or userscripts running?

Comment: I disabled all plugins for testing no changes

Comment: I restarted the browser and this issue is gone.

Comment: It looks like you were blocking the font used for code.

Comment: Funny I had the same bug within the last month again