# Why am I seeing Unicode replacement characters in code blocks when using Firefox to open SO?

Tags: support

This is with Windows 11. (I've only seen this in the last two days and have been using Windows 11 for months.)

For example, the following question:

*[How can I set CSS name not to be hash in a Webpack configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052080/how-to-set-css-name-not-to-be-hash-in-webpack-configuration-file)*

[image]

Also if I try and ask a question (on meta) about this (with Firefox) I get the following:

[image]

Update: I restarted Firefox and now am no longer seeing the issue.

Comment: This is the second report of this this week: [Code highlighting broken?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412651/code-highlighting-broken). Have you tried clearing cache and restarting browser?

Comment: @Nick - restarting browser worked. I guess maybe a partial Firefox background upgrade? Firefox now reports as 93.0

Comment: Same case as last time then, very bizarre, well at least your problem is solved :p