# Broken editor and `code` in SO posts (Firefox)

Tags: bug, editor

It appears that the editor is somehow broken in Firefox. Or is it only me?

First noticed in this post [Clean up working copy which has a deleted file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69850578/76109)

But now here is what I see when composing this post:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the new beta editor?

Comment: @Makoto I don't know, but I did not opt in to test the new beta editor.

Comment: So probably not, then.  What version of Firefox are you running and what is your OS?  It looks fine to me, Firefox 94 on Pop!_OS 21.04.

Comment: I've seen this issue here before..

Comment: @Makoto Firefox 94.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10 64-bit (Version 10.0.19044 Build 19044)

Comment: Over here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412651/code-highlighting-broken

Comment: This is now the third report of this issue, Kevin has linked first, second is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412752/why-am-i-seeing-unicode-replacement-characters-in-code-blocks-when-using-firefox. Both prior were resolved by restarting FF.